# Powershell multiple string replacement using while cycle

Tags: string, powershell, replace, while-loop

I am trying to solve a somewhat weird problem: I need to replace strings within a raw content by strings from the same content that meet a certain matching criteria. The input data look like this:

```
apple-beta
apple-alpha_orange-beta
apple-alpha_orange-alpha_cherry-beta
apple-alpha_orange-alpha_kiwi-beta
apple-alpha_orange-alpha_mango-beta
abcd-alpha_efgh-beta
abcd-alpha_efgh-alpha_ijkl-beta
abcd-alpha_efgh-alpha_mnop-beta
```

The replacment should work as follows: look for all "-beta" strings in the content and delete all according "-alpha" strings (eg because there is "orange-beta" already => all "orange-alpha" should be deleted, because there is "apple-beta" already => all "apple-alpha" should be deleted etc.). The result would look like this:

```
apple-beta
_orange-beta
__cherry-beta
__kiwi-beta
__mango-beta
abcd-alpha_efgh-beta
abcd-alpha__ijkl-beta
abcd-alpha__mnop-beta
```

I have tried to achieve this with a number of awkward single replacements and temporary file storages as well as with a while-construction that doesn't work at all:

```
$whileinput = get-content -raw C:\content-input.txt
while ($whileinput -match "\w+-beta") { 
    $fullval = $whileinput -match "\w+-beta" -replace "-beta","-alpha"
    $whileinput = $whileinput -replace '$fullval',''

    }
```

Any help is very appreciated!
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find all your beta items. Then replace the corresponding alpha items.

```
$data = Get-Content C:\content-input.txt

$betas = ([regex]::Matches($data,'[^_]*?(?=-beta)').Value -ne '' | Foreach-Object {
    [regex]::Escape($_)} ) -join '|'
$data -replace "($betas)-alpha"
```

---

**Explanation:**

`[regex]::Matches().Value` returns only the matched texts.

`[^_]*?` lazily matches consecutive characters that are not `_`. `(?=-beta)` is a positive lookahead for the text `-beta` but doesn't include the text in the match.

`-ne ''` is to filter out blank output.

`[regex]::Escape()` is not necessarily needed in this case. But it is good practice when your text may have special regex characters that you want to match literally.

`$betas` contains `|` delimited items because `|` is the regex `OR`. Using `()` to surround the `$betas` string allows one of those words to be fully matched before matching `-alpha` in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content` gets the entire contents of a file into a variable, so if anything in your file matches that pattern, it'll loop infinitely (because the contents of the file always match your pattern).

PowerShell is heavily based around the concept of the "pipeline" which you can use in conjunction with the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet to iterate over each line in a file.

I'm not quite clear on what you want the regexes to do, but I don't think the ones you have will do what you want. Try this.

```
Get-Content -raw C:\content-input.txt | Foreach-Object { 
    if($_ -match 'beta$') {
        $out+=$_ -replace '\w+-alpha',''
    }
}

$out | Out-File .\path-to-output.txt
```

`$_` is the default "pipeline variable" aka the current item in the iteration - in this case the current line. Now at least your loop is working!

Comment: Hi @flashbang, this solution indeed repairs the loop, but it also deletes the value "abcd-alpha". But it helps me to understand the loop topic better. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. I didn't spend too much time on messing with the regexes because that didn't seem to be your main concern in your post. Good luck!